# pug form - lost field value

Tags: html, forms, pug

I have a form build with pug. The problem affects only 2 of the fields - when I hit Tab the values of this fields are lost. The fields are empty after about a second after change focus to another field.

I have no idea what is going on and how to search for the answer. Have You ever met with something like this?

Here is the part of this form; the problem is with 'bank' and 'bic' fields

```
.form-group#bank
  input.form-control(type="text" name="bank" placeholder="Name Kreditinstitut *")
.form-group#iban
  input.form-control(type="text" name="iban" placeholder="IBAN *")
.form-group#bic
  input.form-control(type="text" name="bic" placeholder="BIC *")
```

Comment: Hmm, it seems to work fine for me. You say that if you switch to a different field, the value is lost? Is that always or just if you post the form? For me if I tab through the fields it works fine.

Comment: It happens when I switch field using tab before even trying to send the form. Whats more the problem is only with this two fields

Comment: Weird. I used your code and for me nothing bad happens.